# My html does not connect with my css while using flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

Im new to html css and flask and have been having this problem where my css code will ony parcaly interract my my hmtl

heres the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Test</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Heres the css:

```
h2 {
    
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
    text-align: center;
    color: aquamarine;

}
```

And heres the python altho i dont think it has anyhing to do with it:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, url_for, render_template

app = Flask("__main__")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My html is returning Test in comic sans tho it is not centralized nor in aquamarine

Comment: Have you created a 'static' folder at the root of your project and added the 'main.css' file in it ?

Comment: i have a folder with the .py, the templates folder and the static folder if thats what u mean

Comment: did you try shift-command-r or shift-ctrl-r to refresh the page?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked but if i try to add new code and ctrl+shift+r it dosent update

Comment: Nvrm it just worked thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because of browser caching.
You can easily solve this problem by clicking CRTL + F5 every time you update your static files (css/js)